# How do I create a new usergroup on a Mac partition?

Tags: dual-boot, macosx

I want to do this because I'm trying to fix user permissions from Ubuntu on my Mac OS X partition and Ubuntu doesn't have the "wheel" group that I so desperately need!

Please don't trash me for this but I set my whole Mac OS X partition to give read and write access to everyone so I could access and modify everything on it from my dual-booting Ubuntu OS, and now everything is screwed...

I don't have the original Mac OS X installation DVD and booting a Mac OS X 10.5.6 DVD gives me kernel panics... The OS installed on that Mac partition is 10.4.11.

Is there any hope for me to ever fix it?

I don't have money to buy utilities, and I can't use AppleJack either because my permissions are so messed up...

None of the posted answers are what I wanted to do. I wanted to add fields to a user that was on my Mac partition, not a user part of the Ubuntu groups. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you're trying to accomplish here (big picture), but here's how to add groups.

```
$ sudo addgroup mygroupname
```

However, system groups like `sudo`, `adm` and `wheel` have a low number group id. Do this for your group `wheel`:

```
$ sudo addgroup --system wheel
```

You should also be able to accomplish this using the GUI ('Users and Groups').

Answer (score 0):

OR you can use advance user settings graphical application.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

None of these are what I wanted to do. I wanted to add fiels to a user that was on my Mac partition, not a user part of the Ubuntu groups. Is that possible?

Comment: Please edit your existing question to make what you want clearer.